# Oracle: Row level trigger to insert a row into a table and update another table's column

Tags: oracle, row, database-trigger

I have three tables that has the following columns:

- Employee: Employee_ID, total_project_budget
- Project: Project_ID, budget
- WorkingOn: Employee_ID, Project_ID

I am trying to create a row level trigger in Oracle when a row is inserted into WorkingOn table. It will get the sum of project's budget and update into employee's total_project_budget that the employee is working on.

My current row level trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER testtrigger
AFTER INSERT ON WorkingOn
FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    UPDATE employee
    SET TOTAL_BUDGET = ( SELECT SUM(budget)
                         FROM project INNER JOIN workingon
                         ON project.project_id = workson.project_id
                         WHERE workingon.employee_id = employee.employee_id )
    WHERE employee_id = :NEW.employee_id;
  END;
/
```

If I run this trigger i get mutating table,

> ORA-04091: table user.WORKINGON is mutating, trigger/function may not see it

However if i run with AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION,

> ORA-06519: active autonomous transaction detected and rolled back

EDIT:

To clarify,
WorkingOn: Employee_ID references Employee.employee_ID, Project_ID references Project.project_ID.

Employee -(1 to 1)-> WorkingOn -(1 to *)-> Project

Comment: Why join on the workingon table to project, if you already have the employee's project_id from either the `:old` or `:new` records? Remove that join and reference the field directly, e.g. `from project where project_id = :new.project_id`

Comment: I think the desired sum is not specific to an individual project id but to employee id which might contain multiple project id @Boneist .

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan I guess it depends on whether `workingon.employee_id` is a primary/unique key (as I was assuming) or not. Only the OP can tell us!

Comment: well, maybe so :) @Boneist

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan although taking a second look at the tables, perhaps I’ve got the wrong end of the stick. However, if the working table has multiple projects per person, surely `set total_budget = total_budget + (select budget from project where project_id = :new.employee_id)`, rather than summing every time is better. Assuming an employee/project link is unique.

Comment: yes @Boneist , this is a nice approach I think. Keeping aside the question, indeed, it's a wrong style to store a value which can already been calculated in my opinion.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan you are, of course, absolutely correct!

Comment: @Boneist I did not think of this approach. Thanks! I was able to get what i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use sum only on project table as following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER testtrigger
AFTER INSERT ON WorkingOn
FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    UPDATE employee
    SET TOTAL_BUDGET = ( SELECT SUM(budget)
                         FROM project 
                        WHERE project.project_id = :NEW.project_id)
    WHERE employee_id = :NEW.employee_id;
  END;
/
```

Cheers!!